# Question regarding FamaMcBeth regression

Tags: time-series, beta-distribution, cross-section

I'm new here and hope you can help me with three questions I'm having in regard to the FamaMcBeth regression methodology.

1. What is the advantage of using firm specific returns instead of an aggregate market return (like Goyal and Welch, 2008)?
2. How should I interpret the lambdas produced in the second step?
3. I read the lambdas should be standardised why is that?

Many thanks in advance!

Robey

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please elaborate by posting a link to the Fama-McBeth methodology to which you are referring.

Comment: Hi Jim, thank you for your reply. The Fama-McBeth regression (or two step procedure) is employed in for example Chen, Roll and Ross (1986) (https://rady.ucsd.edu/faculty/directory/valkanov/pub/classes/mfe/docs/ChenRollRoss_JB_1986.pdf). Also it is explained more elaborately in Asset Pricing by Cochrane (http://ecsocman.hse.ru/data/018/648/1219/finbook.pdf)